# SWT RowLayout: what is the minimum size?

Tags: java, layout, swt

I must be missing something  stupid. The [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/RowData.html) clearly state that the RowData object for the RowLayout layout lets you specify a minimum size (width and height), which makes sense. However, when the underlying widget exceeds this size, the size does not increases and the widget is cropped. Is it really a minimum?

Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Example");
    shell.setBounds(100, 100, 325, 200);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    comp.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    Label label1 = new Label(comp, SWT.CENTER);
    label1.setLayoutData(new RowData(20,20));
    label1.setText("Trying with bounded rowdata...");

    Label label2 = new Label(comp, SWT.CENTER);
    label2.setText("Trying with no rowdata...");


    comp.layout(true,true); // no difference
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying yo achieve here?

Comment: This is just an example. But what I want is what the docs seem imply: to set a minimun size for a widget inside a layout, so that it gets at least that size.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc of the constructor `RowData(int, int)` must be wrong! If you read carrefully the header of the `RowData` javadoc,  it is said that `RowData` are used to set an initial size for `Controls`, not the minimum. That's why your `Label`is croped by a square of 20x20 px!

Comment: I beg to differ. According to the JavaDoc of [`RowData(int width, int height)`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/RowData.html#RowData(int,%20int)): `width` - a minimum width for the control `height` - a minimum height for the control. So it should indeed set the _minimal_ sizes, not the initial ones.

Comment: My mistake! I didn't read the javadoc of this version of the constructor... It must be a javadoc error....

Answer (score 0):

Try turning packing off on the layout:

```
Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
RowLayout layout = new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL);
layout.pack = false;
comp.setLayout(layout);
```

On the other hand you can also consider using a [`GridLayout`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.eclipse.org%2Fhelp32%2Ftopic%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridLayout.html&ei=bZW8UKscjoiFB_SfgYAE&usg=AFQjCNFErftm2BOjct-5Gmmj_jx9KQI3mg&sig2=86n-2ax610HEVuLU5kHpuw) if you want the controls to resize with respect to their parents but not less than a minimum width. The minimum width works with `GridData`.